# Select Next/Previous list item in React without re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React. Say that I have a `ListContainer` which renders several `ListItems`. I want to keep track of the currently selected `ListItem`, render it in another color, and be able to navigate up and down.

One way would be to store `selectedItem` as state in `ListContainer`, and send it down as a prop to `ListItem`. But if I do it this way, then every time I change `selectedItem` I will rerender all `ListItems` because they are dependent on `selectedItem`. (I should only have to re-render two `ListItems`, the one that gets deselected, and the one that gets selected).

Is there a way to implement next and previous function without re-rendering all items?

Note: I know that React doesn't re-render unnecessarily in the DOM, but I'm trying to optimize operations on virtual DOM also.

Edit: Here is my example in code. It renders a list, and when the user click one item it gets selected. We also see that "ListItem update" gets printed 100 times, each time we change selection, which happens regardless of `PureComponent` or `React.memo`.

```
let mylist = []
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  mylist.push({ text: "node:" + i, id: i })
}

window.mylist = mylist

const ListItem = React.memo (class extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('ListItem update')
  }

  render() {
    let backgroundColor = this.props.item.id === this.props.selectedItem ? 'lightgreen' : 'white'
    return (
      <li
        style={{ backgroundColor }}
        onMouseDown={() => this.props.setSelected(this.props.item.id)}
      >
        {this.props.item.text}
      </li>
    )
  }
})

class ListContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedItem: 10
    }
    this.setSelected = this.setSelected.bind(this)
  }

  setSelected(id) {
    this.setState({ selectedItem: id })
    this.forceUpdate()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.list.map(item =>
          <ListItem
            item={item}
            key={item.id}
            selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem}
            setSelected={this.setSelected}
          />)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <ListContainer list={mylist} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Ti think he expected an example...

Comment: You can wrap a react memo on the `ListItem` to prevent rerendering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state you suggesting is the right way to implement it...
The other problem with unnecessary renders of the list item can easily be soved by wrapping the export statement like this:

```
export default React.memo(ListItem)
```

This way the only elements that has changed their props will rerender.. be aware that overuse of This can cause memory leaks when using it unnecessarily...

**UPDATE**

according to your example in addition to the `React.memo` you can update the way you transfer props to avoid senfing the selected item in each item...

istead of:

```
let backgroundColor = this.props.item.id === this.props.selectedItem ? 'lightgreen' : 'white'
...
<ListItem
            item={item}
            key={item.id}
            selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem}
            setSelected={this.setSelected}
          />)}
```

do :

```
let backgroundColor = this.props.selectedItem ? 'lightgreen' : 'white'
...
<ListItem
            item={item}
            key={item.id}
            selectedItem={item.id === this.state.selectedItem}
            setSelected={this.setSelected}
          />)}
```

this way the react memo will prevent rerenders when it is possible...

Comment: In this case though, changing `selectedItem` will change props for all `ListItems`, and cause them to re-render, even when using React.memo, I think.

Comment: It wont cause them to rerender as long as no prop is changing and key property is designed well... try to test it ...

Comment: But props are changing, because I need to let `ListItem` know about `selectedItem`. I added code to my example (and tried `React.memo`) to make things more clear.